# New controller does not respond to requests

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a new project from the ASP.NET Core Web API template in Visual Studio, and attempted to add a new controller, but I get a 404 response with this message when trying to GET from it:

> ```
> Cannot GET /navigation
> ```

My program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The working controller that came with the template:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Test.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

My new controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Test.API.Navigation;

namespace Test.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class NavigationController : ControllerBase
    {
        public NavigationController()
        {

        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetNavigation")]
        public IEnumerable<NavigationItem> Get()
        {
            return new List<NavigationItem>
            {
                new NavigationItem()
                {
                    Title = "Home",
                    Url = "test",
                    AltText = "Home page"
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this controller to work? The project seems to have no extra config files that are relevant, just launchsettings.json and applicationsettings.json.

I tried changing the name of the WeatherForecastController, which led to it returning the same response, so it feels like it is hardcoded somehow.

Comment: Provide us the full URL you are calling

Comment: I made a brand new .Net 6 Web API project, pasted in your code. I can do a `GET /navigation`, returns the information just fine. There might be something we can't see that affecting your routing. Try increasing the logging to Debug in the different appsettings files, and walk through the steps to make a [mre].

Comment: @Andre.Santarosa https://localhost:5002/weatherforecast does work and returns what is expected, https://localhost:5002/weatherforecast/GetWeatherForecast returns a 404 with no body, https://localhost:5002/navigation/GetNavigation and https://localhost:5002/navigation return what I posted in the original post

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your proxy.conf.js file? Change the context to `/navigation`. The target is your target you have now.

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/navigation",
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7105",
    secure: false
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```